# error using iterators in graph

Tags: c++, graph, stl

```
void Graph::removeEdge( int u , Edge e )
{
    for( std::list<Edge> iterator i = AdjList[u].begin() ;
                             i != AdjList[u].end() ;
                             ++i )
    {
        if( i->vertex() == e.vertex() )
        {
            AdjList[u].erase(i) ;
            break ;
        }
    }
}
```

I have used this function in a `graph` class and during compiling I am getting the following errors

```
|In member function ‘void Graph::removeEdge(int, Edge)’:|
|47|error: expected ‘;’ before ‘i’|
|47|error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope|
|48|error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token|
|49|error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope|
|49|error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token|
|59|error: expected ‘}’ at end of input|
```

, please help me out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two variable names or types in a declaration. Your compiler expects you just to say `std::list<Edge> iterator;`. However, you probably meant this, since `iterator` is a `typedef` within the class `std::list<Edge>`:

```
std::list<Edge>::iterator i = AdjList[u].begin();
```

However, note that you can use `std::find_if` to locate the element:

```
std::list<Edge>::iterator it = std::find_if(AdjList[u].begin(), AdjList[u].end(), 
    [&e](const Edge &edge) {return edge.vertex() == e.vertex();}
);

if (it != AdjList[u].end()) {
    AdjList[u].erase(it);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're missing a `::` here.

```
for( std::list<Edge>::iterator i = AdjList[u].begin() ;
```